# Router Link rewrite url params

Tags: angular, routes

my application starts with the following path http://example.com/start and after I used [routerLink] I want that the start substring will be overwritten.

I've tried to change my routing within Angular and I was searching on the Internet but I didn't find any solution. If I click on the link then my path will look like this http://example.com/start/newStart/123

```
<a [routerLink]="['/newStart', id]></a>
```

My routing looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/start', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'star', component: StartComponent },
  { path: ':id/:id', component: NewComponent },
  { path: '**', component: StartComponent }
];
```

What I want is if I click on  link the URL path from

http://example.com/start

should be

http://example.com/newStart/123

**SOLUTION**

This works for me. I just add the slash before newStart.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/newStart', id]">
```

Comment: <a routerLink="/newStart"></a>

Comment: Try:`<a [routerLink]="['/newStart/'+id]></a>`

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-example-123).

Using the following links:

```
<a [routerLink]="['start']">Start</a>
<a [routerLink]="['newStart', 123]">New start</a>
```

and the following route definitions:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'start', component: StartComponent },
  { path: 'newStart/:id', component: NewComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'start' }
];
```

with two components `StartComponent` and `NewComponent`,
angular will redirect you to the `StartComponent` on load (`example.com` -> `example.com/start`).

When you click the `newStart` link, the url will become `example.com/newStart/123` and the router will load the `NewComponent` with a routing param `id = 123`.

Comment: Very strange. It is not working on my machine even. I am running my app first time and the path ist localhost:4200/start and then if I click on the link and I adjust my routes like yours but not working. I am getting localhost:4200/start/newstart. If I mouseover the link and I have also localhost:4200/start/newstart

Comment: Could you provide a Stackblitz of your code, or a minimal reproduction?

Comment: Hi, please check above. I found a solution.